# Webkit @font-face rendering issue - some elements do not use the font

Tags: html, css, firefox, webkit, font-face

I'm busy building a site on my local server, and I'm using Firefox to test it. Now, it's reached a Milestone, and so I have to check that it works in every browser. Unfortunately, Webkit-based browsers seem to be having a problem rendering my fonts in certain places, even where their styles match. Here's an image to demonstrate:

---

[image: webkit font problem...]

---

See how the button loads Arial instead of the paragraph's font (Source Sans Pro)? Even worse, what happened to the padding? It's supposed to look like this (at least, Firefox shows it like this):

---

[image: webkit font problem...]

---

Now, that paragraph and that button inherit the font styles from the parent container, and do not specify styles of their own. Firefox shows it correctly, but any Webkit-based browser does not. The console does not show a thing, and I have verified that all the font files are loading. (I provide two formats: SVG and WOFF; the latter is always loaded in the browsers I test with - I may as well remove the SVG anyway.)

This is the CSS @font-face declaration:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceSansPro';
    src: url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/woffRegular') format('woff'),
         url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/svgRegular#source_sans_proregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And this is the HTML block:

```
<div class="grid4 uniformFund">
    <img class="blockImage" src="//www1-resources.aaa-kee.co.za.dev/png/funds/uniform-fund/logo.png" width="228" height="40" alt="The Uniform Fund - Logo">
    <p>In South Africa, a uniform is required for attendance at most schools - without one a child may not be able to attend school.<br><br>As it is, thousands of children across the country do not have the privilege of having one at their disposal.</p>
    <a class="readMoreButton" href="/fund/uniform-fund">Read more &rarr;</a>
</div>
```

Any ideas why this happens?

#### UPDATE

Also, I don't think it has anything to do with element types. In the below example, you'll see that Firefox loads the two buttons properly, but Chrome does not (it only loads the first one correctly).

[image: buttons]

#### UPDATE - LESS FILES

Here are my LESS files:

#### 1. main.less

```
html {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: @paragraphColor;
    cursor: default;
    .paragraphFont;
    height: 100%;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
body {
    border-top: 5px solid #2a2a2a;
}
a {
    color: @baseColor;
    text-decoration: none;
    &[href]:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
}
a.commonButton, button.commonButton {
    background-color: @baseColor;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 0;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 11px 16px;
    .transition(.1s background-color ease-out);
    .boxShadow(0 1px 2px, fade(#000, 10%));
    &:hover {
        background-color: @lighterColor;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    &:hover:active {
        background-color: @baseColor !important;
        .boxShadow(inset 0 1px 2px, darken(@baseColor, 10%));
        margin-top: 1px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}
.mouseDefault {
    cursor: default;
}
header[role=siteNavigation] {
    > div.backFade {
        .gradientTopBottom(fade(desaturate(@baseColor, 30%), 17%), rgba(255,255,255,0));
        display: none;
        height: 800px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 97;
    }
    .headerBlock {
        margin: 27px auto;
        blockquote.mainQuote {
            color: #ff9e42;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-style: italic;
            font-weight: 600;
            line-height: 130%;
            margin-top: 11px;
            cite {
                color: #d6d6d6;
            }
        }
        .socialButtons {
            padding: 20px 0 0 40px;
            a {
                background: #fff url("@{resPath}/png/social/buttonMap") no-repeat 0 0;
                display: inline-block;
                float: left;
                margin: 0 2px;
                height: 35px;
                width: 35px;
                text-indent: -9999px;
                &.facebook {
                    background-position: 0 0;
                    &:hover {
                        background-position: 0 -35px;
                    }
                }
                &.googlePlus {
                    background-position: -35px 0;
                    &:hover {
                        background-position: -35px -35px;
                    }
                }
                &.twitter {
                    background-position: -70px 0;
                    &:hover {
                        background-position: -70px -35px;
                    }
                }
                &.rssFeeds {
                    background-position: -105px 0;
                    &:hover {
                        background-position: -105px -35px;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .siteLogo {
            background: #fff url('@{resPath}/png/logo') no-repeat 0 0;
            float: right;
            height: 65px;
            text-indent: -9999px;
            width: 185px;
        }
    }
    nav.siteMainMenu {
        margin-bottom: 2px;
        .line {
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            height: 5px;
            margin-top: 34px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: -1;
        }
        .menuPlaceHolder {
            > ul > li {
                background: #fff;
                display: inline-block;
                float: left;
                overflow: hidden;
                padding-right: 2px;
                &:first-child {
                    padding-left: 2px
                }
                > div {
                    background-color: #fff;
                    border-radius: 0 5px 4px 4px;
                    border-top: 5px solid @baseColor;
                    display: none;
                    margin-top: -5px;
                    padding: 8px 0;
                    position: absolute;
                    z-index: 100;
                    .boxShadow(0 12px 15px; rgba(0,0,0,0.15));
                    ul {
                        display: inline-block;
                        float: left;
                        margin-left: -1px;
                        min-width: 200px;
                        &:first-child {
                            margin-left: 0;
                        }
                        li {
                            &.break {
                                border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
                                height: 0px;
                                margin: 8px 0;
                            }
                            &.groupTitle {
                                border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
                                color: #ccc;
                                font-size: 12px;
                                font-weight: 800;
                                margin-bottom: 8px;
                                padding: 14px 18px 8px;
                                text-transform: uppercase;
                            }
                            > a {
                                color: #808080;
                                display: block;
                                font-size: 12px;
                                font-weight: 600;
                                padding: 9px 19px;
                                text-transform: uppercase;
                                &[href]:hover, &.current {
                                    background-color: #efefef;
                                    .gradientTopBottom(#efefef, #f4f4f4);
                                    .boxShadow(inset 0 1px 2px, #e4e4e4);
                                    color: @baseColor;
                                    text-decoration: none;
                                }
                                > span {
                                    background-color: #ccc;
                                    border-radius: 4px;
                                    color: #777;
                                    font-size: 11px;
                                    font-weight: 600;
                                    margin-left: 8px;
                                    padding: 1px 5px 0;
                                    &.new {
                                        background-color: #ff9e42;
                                        color: #fff;
                                        font-weight: 900;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            &.largeItem {
                                > a[href] {
                                    color: #444;
                                    font-size: 14px;
                                    line-height: 1.3em;
                                    max-width: 240px;
                                    text-transform: none;
                                    span.descriptor {
                                        background: none;
                                        display: block;
                                        font-size: 12px;
                                        font-weight: 400;
                                        margin: 8px 0 0 0;
                                        padding: 0;
                                    }
                                    &:hover {
                                        color: @baseColor;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        &.borderLeft {
                            border-left: 1px solid #eee;
                        }
                        &.borderRight {
                            border-right: 1px solid #eee;
                        }
                    }
                }
                > a {
                    border-bottom: 5px solid #e6e6e6;
                    color: #909090;
                    display: block;
                    font-size: 16px;
                    padding: 9px 18px;
                    position: relative;
                    text-transform: lowercase;
                    transition: .2s color ease-out;
                }
                &:hover > a[href],
                > a[href]:hover,
                > a.current {
                    .gradientTopBottom(#fff, lighten(@baseColor, 50%));
                    border-bottom: 5px solid #2e75b6;
                    color: @baseColor;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
                }
            }
            > ul > li.donate {
                > a {
                    color: #b2923f;
                    font-weight: 400;
                }
                &:hover > a[href],
                > a[href]:hover,
                > a.current {
                    .gradientTopBottom(#fff, lighten(#7a5f07, 65%));
                    border-bottom: 5px solid #7a5f07;
                    color: #7a5f07;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
                }
                > div {
                    border-top-color: #7a5f07;
                }
            }
            > form#siteSearch {
                border-bottom: 0;
                display: inline-block;
                float: right;
                margin-top: 3px;
                > input[type=text] {
                    border: 0;
                    display: inline-block;
                    float: left;
                    .inputFont;
                    line-height: 1em;
                    outline: 0;
                    padding: 5px 6px;
                    width: 140px;
                    margin: 0;
                    .transition(.4s width ease-out);
                    &:focus {
                        width: 193px;
                    }
                }
                > input[type=submit] {
                    background: #fff url("@{resPath}/png/search/submit") no-repeat 50% 50%;
                    border: 0;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    display: inline-block;
                    float: right;
                    margin: 0;
                    min-height: 27px;
                    min-width: 30px;
                    outline: 0;
                    padding: 6px;
                    &:hover {
                        background-color: #f1f1f1;
                    }
                    &:hover:active {
                        background-color: #e6e6e6;
                        background-position: 50% 60%;
                        .boxShadow(inset 0 1px 2px, #ccc);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
main[role="documentContent"] {
    #homeIntro {
        padding: 30px 0;
        background: @baseColor url("@{resPath}/png/elements/blue-pattern");
        .boxShadow(inset 0 0 50px, @darkerColor);
        .content p {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 1.4em;
        }
        .callToActionButtons {
            > a.button {
                background-color: #0061be;
                color: #fff;
                display: block;
                font-size: 16px;
                font-weight: 400;
                margin-left: 10px;
                padding: 14px 20px;
                .transition(.2s background-color ease-out, .2s color ease-out);
                &:first-child {
                    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
                }
                &:last-child {
                    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
                }
                &:hover {
                    background-color: #0056b2;
                    text-decoration: none;
                }
                &:hover:active {
                    .boxShadow(inset 0 1px 2px, fade(#000, 20%));
                    padding: 15px 20px 13px;
                }
                &.white {
                    background: #fff;
                    color: #0061be;
                    &:hover {
                        background: #b6e5ff;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #breadCrumbs {
        background: #f7f7f7;
        .gradientTopBottom(#f7f7f7, #fff);
        color: #aaa;
        padding: 20px 0 10px;
        a[itemprop="url"] {
            color: @lighterColor;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    }
    #pageContent {
        margin: 40px auto;
        .headerBlock {
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            .blockTitle {
                background: #fff url("@{resPath}/png/elements/block-header-line") repeat-x 50% 50%;
                h1 {
                    background-color: #fff;
                    display: inline-block;
                    font-size: 27px;
                    font-weight: 100;
                    padding: 0 20px 0 0;
                }
            }
        }
        .contentBlock {
            line-height: 150%;
            p {
                margin-bottom: 14px;
                &.introText {
                    font-size: 15px;
                    font-weight: 700;
                }
            }
            ul.contentList, ol.contentList {
                margin-left: 17px;
                li {
                    padding: 0 0 10px 10px;
                    &:last-child {
                        padding-bottom: 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            ul.contentList {
                list-style-image: url("@{resPath}/png/elements/content-bullet");
            }
            h1, h2 {
                color: @baseColor;
                font-size: 17px;
                margin: 27px 0 10px 0;
            }
            h1.pageTitle {
                color: @baseColor;
                font-size: 26px;
                font-weight: 400;
                padding: 0 0 30px;
                margin: 0;
            }
            h2 {
                font-size: 15px;
                font-weight: 400;
            }
            img {
                .userSelect(none);
                &.blockImage {
                    display: block;
                    margin-bottom: 30px;
                    &.bordered {
                        border: 1px solid #ccc;
                        padding: 4px;
                        .boxShadow(0 1px 8px, #eee);
                    }
                }
            }
            a {
                &.readMoreButton {
                    border-radius: 2px;
                    border: 3px solid #ccc;
                    color: #484848;
                    display: inline-block;
                    margin: 10px 0 1px;
                    padding: 4px 16px;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    .transition(.2s background-color ease-out, .2s color ease-out);
                    .boxShadow(0 1px 2px, fade(#000, 10%));
                    &:hover {
                        background-color: #aaa;
                        border-color: #aaa;
                        color: #fff;
                        text-decoration: none;
                    }
                    &:hover:active {
                        .destroyBoxShadow();
                        margin: 11px 0 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            .foodFund {
                a.readMoreButton {
                    border-color: @foodFundColor;
                    &:hover {
                        background-color: @foodFundColor;
                    }
                }
            }
            .activeEducationFund {
                a.readMoreButton {
                    border-color: @activeEducationFundColor;
                    &:hover {
                        background-color: @activeEducationFundColor;
                    }
                }
            }
            .uniformFund {
                a.readMoreButton {
                    border-color: @uniformFundColor;
                    &:hover {
                        background-color: @uniformFundColor;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        aside .asideBlock {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            h1 {
                background-color: @baseColor;
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 15px;
                font-weight: 400;
                padding: 7px 14px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }
            a.donate {
                border-radius: 4px;
                border: 3px solid @baseColor;
                color: @baseColor;
                display: block;
                font-size: 18px;
                font-weight: 700;
                padding: 10px 5px;
                text-align: center;
                .transition(.3s background-color ease-out, .3s color ease-out, .3s text-shadow ease-out);
                &:hover {
                    background-color: lighten(@baseColor,10%);
                    color: #fff;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px darken(@baseColor, 2%);
                }
                &:hover:active {
                    .boxShadow(inset 0 1px 3px, darken(@baseColor, 2%));
                    padding: 11px 5px 9px;
                    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px darken(@baseColor, 2%);
                }
            }
            ul {
                list-style: none;
                li a {
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
                    color: #444;
                    display: block;
                    padding: 5px 14px;
                    &:hover,
                    &.current {
                        background-color: #f1f1f1;
                        color: @baseColor;
                        text-decoration: none;
                    }
                    > span {
                        background-color: #ccc;
                        border-radius: 4px;
                        color: #777;
                        font-size: 11px;
                        font-weight: 600;
                        margin-left: 8px;
                        padding: 1px 5px 0;
                        text-transform: uppercase;
                        &.new {
                            background-color: #ff9e42;
                            color: #fff;
                            font-weight: 900;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #donatePartner {
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 40px 0;
        border-top: 5px solid #eee;
        &.e5c7b864a6ef {
            border-top-color: #fdd00e;
            a {
                background: #fff url("@{resPath}/png/donate-partner/e5c7b864a6ef") no-repeat top center;
                display: block;
                height: 67px;
                text-indent: -9999px;
            }
        }
    }
    #baseNavigation {
        background: #2a2a2a url("@{resPath}/png/elements/dark-fabric");
        margin-bottom: 1px;
        padding: 40px 0;
        div {
            h1.blockTitle {
                background: fade(#fff, 10%);
                color: #fff;
                font-weight: 400;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                padding: 8px 11px 7px;
                margin-bottom: 2px;
            }
            a {
                font-size: 13px;
                color: #ccc;
                span {
                    display: block;
                    &.image {
                        background: #2a2a2a url('@{resPath}/png/base-navigation/arrow') center center no-repeat;
                        display: block;
                        img {
                            .userSelect(none);
                            .transition(.3s opacity ease-out);
                        }
                    }
                    &.text {
                        display: block;
                        padding-top: 10px;
                    }
                }
                &:hover {
                    color: #fff;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    img {
                        opacity: 0.6;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
footer[role="mainFooter"] {
    #latestJournalEntry {
        padding: 30px 0;
        background: @baseColor url("@{resPath}/png/elements/blue-pattern");
        &:hover .header h1 {
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        .boxShadow(inset 0 0 50px, @darkerColor);
        .header h1 {
            border-radius: 4px;
            background-color: fade(#fff, 70%);
            padding: 16px 14px 13px;
            color: @baseColor;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: 200;
            margin-right: 10px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            .transition(.3s background-color ease-out);
            span {
                font-size: 38px;
                font-weight: 800;
                &.padder {
                    font-size: 16px;
                    font-weight: 200;
                    display: inline;
                    margin-left: 9px;
                }
            }
        }
        .content {
            color: #fff;
            h1 {
                font-size: 24px;
                font-weight: 200;
                a {
                    color: #fff;
                }
            }
            p {
                color: lighten(@baseColor, 30%);
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: 400;
                margin-top: 9px;
                line-height: 1.4em;
                &.credits {
                    border-top: 1px solid fade(#fff,15%);
                    color: lighten(@baseColor, 40%);
                    font-size: 11px;
                    padding-top: 5px;
                    font-weight: 400;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    a {
                        color: #fff;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #fatFooter {
        background: #eee url("@{resPath}/png/elements/light-swirl");
        padding: 30px 0;
        margin: 1px 0;
        h1.groupTitle {
            color: @baseColor;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 400;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        ul.links {
            li {
                font-size: 12px;
                overflow: hidden;
                a {
                    color: #4f4f4f;
                    display: block;
                    padding-bottom: 5px;
                    &:hover {
                        color: @baseColor;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .nextEvent {
            a {
                display: block;
                line-height: 1.3em;
                overflow: hidden;
                span {
                    display: block;
                    &.date {
                        background-color: @baseColor;
                        border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
                        color: #fff;
                        font-weight: 200;
                        font-size: 22px;
                        padding: 10px;
                        .transition(.3s background-color ease-out; .3s color ease-out);
                        strong {
                            font-weight: 800;
                        }
                    }
                    &.eventName {
                        background-color: #fff;
                        border: 1px solid @baseColor;
                        border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
                        color: #444;
                        font-size: 14px;
                        font-weight: 400;
                        line-height: 1.7em;
                        padding: 5px 10px;
                        .transition(.3s color ease-out; .3s border-color ease-out);
                        span.eventType {
                            background-color: lighten(@baseColor, 50%);
                            border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
                            line-height: 1.7em;
                            margin-left: -10px;
                            margin-right: 5px;
                            margin-top: -10px;
                            color: @baseColor;
                            display: inline-block;
                            font-size: 10px;
                            padding: 0 6px 0 10px;
                            text-transform: uppercase;
                        }
                    }
                }
                &:hover{
                    text-decoration: none;
                    .transition(.3s box-shadow ease-out);
                    span.date {
                        background-color: @lighterColor;
                    }
                    span.eventName {
                        color: @baseColor;
                        border: 1px solid @lighterColor;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #baseFooter {
        background: #2a2a2a url("@{resPath}/png/elements/dark-fabric");
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 30px 0;
        p.copyright {
            color: #b9b9b9;
            margin: 7px 0;
            a {
                color: #eee;
            }
        }
        p.certification a {
            color: #999;
        }
        a.foundryStamp {
            background: #2a2a2a url("@{resPath}/png/foundry/footerStamp") no-repeat 0 0;
            border-radius: 4px;
            display: inline-block;
            float: right;
            height: 42px;
            text-indent: -9999px;
            width: 222px;
            .transition(.8s background-position ease-out);
            .boxShadow(inset 0 1px 4px, rgba(0,0,0,0.3));
            &:hover {
                background-position: 0 -42px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### 2. gather.less (this file contains the font assignment definitions)

```
@resPath: "//www1-resources.aaa-kee.co.za.dev";
@sliderSkinPath: "@{resPath}/png/slider/skins";
@sliderSlidesPath: "@{resPath}/png/slider/slides";

@baseColor: #1f74c2;
@lighterColor: #448ddf;
@darkerColor: #005ba7;
@paragraphColor: #6e6e6e;
@foodFundColor: #98d733;
@activeEducationFundColor: #ff00af;
@uniformFundColor: #24adcd;

.font (@size, @lineHeight) {
    font: ~"@{size}/@{lineHeight}" "SourceSansPro", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
}

.paragraphFont () {
    .font(14px, 150%);
}
.inputFont () {
    .font(14px, 100%);
}

.boxShadow (@style, @c) {
    -moz-box-shadow: @style @c;
    -ms-box-shadow: @style @c;
    -webkit-box-shadow: @style @c;
    box-shadow: @style @c;
}
.boxShadowDouble (@style, @c, @style2, @c2) {
    -moz-box-shadow: @style @c, @style2 @c2;
    -ms-box-shadow: @style @c, @style2 @c2;
    -webkit-box-shadow: @style @c, @style2 @c2;
    box-shadow: @style @c, @style2 @c2;
}
.destroyBoxShadow () {
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -ms-box-shadow: none;
    -ms-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.transition (@value1,@value2:X,...)
{
    @value: ~`"@{arguments}".replace(/[\[\]]|\,\sX/g, '')`;
    -moz-transition: @value;
    -ms-transition: @value;
    -o-transition: @value;
    -webkit-transition: @value;
    transition: @value;
}
.animation (@name; @speed: .5s) {
    -moz-animation-duration: @speed;
    -moz-animation-name: @name;
    -ms-animation-name: @name;
    -ms-animation-duration: @speed;
    -o-animation-duration: @speed;
    -o-animation-name: @name;
    -webkit-animation-duration: @speed;
    -webkit-animation-name: @name;
    animation-duration: @speed;
    animation-name: @name;
}
.gradientTopBottom (@top; @bottom) {
    background-color: @bottom;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @top 0%, @bottom 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, @top 0%, @bottom 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, @top 0%, @bottom 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, @top), color-stop(100%, @bottom));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @top 0%, @bottom 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, @top 0%, @bottom 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='@{top}', endColorstr='@{bottom}',GradientType=0 );
}
.gradientRadial (@in; @out) {
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, @in 0%, @out 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%, @out));
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, @in 0%, @out 100%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, @in 0%, @out 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, @in 0%, @out 100%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, @in 0%, @out 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='@{in}', endColorstr='@{out}',GradientType=1 );
}

.userSelect (@value: none) {
    -moz-user-select: @value;
    -webkit-user-select: @value;
    user-select: @value;
}

@import "reset.less";
@import "grid.less";
@import "slider/main.less";
@import "slider/skins/white.less";
@import "slider/slides/active-education.less";
@import "slider/slides/excursion-fund.less";
@import "slider/slides/food-fund.less";
@import "fonts/source-sans-pro.less";
@import "main.less";
```

#### 3. @font-face definitions

```
@sourceSansProFontPath: "@{resPath}/fonts/source-sans-pro";

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceSansPro';
    src: url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/woffBlackItalic') format('woff'),
         url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/svgBlackItalic#source_sans_problack_italic') format('svg');
    font-weight: 900;
    font-style: italic;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceSansPro';
    src: url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/woffBlack') format('woff'),
         url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/svgBlack#source_sans_problack') format('svg');
    font-weight: 900;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceSansPro';
    src: url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/woffBoldItalic') format('woff'),
         url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/svgBoldItalic#source_sans_probold_italic') format('svg');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: italic;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceSansPro';
    src: url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/woffBold') format('woff'),
         url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/svgBold#source_sans_probold') format('svg');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceSansPro';
    src: url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/woffExtraLightItalic') format('woff'),
         url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/svgExtraLightItalic#source_sans_proXLtIt') format('svg');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: italic;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceSansPro';
    src: url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/woffExtraLight') format('woff'),
         url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/svgExtraLight#source_sans_proextralight') format('svg');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceSansPro';
    src: url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/woffItalic') format('woff'),
         url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/svgItalic#source_sans_proitalic') format('svg');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceSansPro';
    src: url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/woffLightItalic') format('woff'),
         url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/svgLightItalic#source_sans_prolight_italic') format('svg');
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: italic;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceSansPro';
    src: url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/woffLight') format('woff'),
         url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/svgLight#source_sans_prolight') format('svg');
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceSansPro';
    src: url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/woffRegular') format('woff'),
         url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/svgRegular#source_sans_proregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceSansPro';
    src: url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/woffSemiboldItalic') format('woff'),
         url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/svgSemiboldItalic#source_sans_proSBdIt') format('svg');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: italic;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceSansPro';
    src: url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/woffSemibold') format('woff'),
         url('@{sourceSansProFontPath}/svgSemibold#source_sans_prosemibold') format('svg');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Comment: Does the question contain enough code to reproduce the problem? I don’t think so. You are effectively asking others to do some basic debugging work for you, with no access to the real code.

Comment: How can I debug when no errors are thrown? I've done everything I can think of. I'll post my `less` directory when I get back to my laptop.

Comment: Also, I don't think that my code has anything to do with it. How can two elements that are extremely similar (the only difference being color) render the fonts differently?

Comment: Okay, I've updated with my main LESS files. Those are the only ones that do anything about font rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution Found:

It seems there is a Webkit bug when one sets `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;`. When I disabled it, everything worked just fine.

Now, this raises the question - why did it do that? And is is really a bug? To me, it is. Simply because of the nature of the displaying of the fonts on certain elements, but not others.